# JQuery Autocomplete returns all results in one string

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, autocomplete

I am currently making a jQuery autocomplete function for a text input in one of my forms. I am using Codeigniter right now.

Here is my Model Code

```
function get_names()
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT CONCAT(tbl_applicant.fname, ' ', tbl_applicant.lname) AS name FROM tbl_applicant INNER JOIN tbl_employee ON tbl_employee.apid=tbl_applicant.apid INNER JOIN tbl_account ON tbl_account.acc_id=tbl_employee.acc_id WHERE tbl_account.acc_description LIKE '%Agent%' AND tbl_employee.isActive LIKE '%yes%'");
    return $query->result();

}
```

Here is my Controller

```
public function index()
{
    if($this->session->userdata('uid'))
    {
        $data['kudos'] = $this->KudosModel->get_kudos();
        $data['acc'] = $this->KudosModel->get_accounts();
        $data['name'] = $this->KudosModel->get_names();
        $this->load->view('kudoslist',$data);
    }
    else
    {
        redirect('index.php/login');
    }
}
```

Here is my JavaScript/jQuery

```
$(function(){
var names="";
"use strict";
     var obj = JSON.parse(<?php echo "'".json_encode($name)."'"; ?>);
    $.each( obj, function( key, value ) {
          names += ',"'+value.name+'"';
    });
     // names += "]";
      var all = [names];
      console.log(all);
               $("#addAmbassadorName2").autocomplete({source: all});
});
```

Now it shows this data
[here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPQD1.png)

Hope you could help me out. Thanks!

Comment: I'm confused, you say it returns all results in one string. by your code, it looks like it is your who make it into one string? `names += ',"'+value.name+'"';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per existing code you creating a string `names += ',"'+value.name+'"';`. As per understanding you need to create an array so [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) can be used.

```
var all = obj.map(function (value) {
    return value.name;
});
$("#addAmbassadorName2").autocomplete({source: all});
```

Comment: Thanks man. It worked. I cant vote since my reputation doesnt meet the requirement to vote. This problem has been bothering me for hours. Thank you again. More power to you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be an array try this if you want to change your own code:

```js
$(function() {
  var names = [];
  "use strict";
  var obj = JSON.parse( <? php echo "'".json_encode($name).
    "'"; ?> );
  $.each(obj, function(key, value) {
    names.push(value.name);
  });
  // names += "]";
  
  console.log(all);
  $("#addAmbassadorName2").autocomplete({
    source: names
  });
});
```

If you want a simple way, try:

```
var all = obj.map(function (value) {
    return value.name;
});
```